# Finding the value of this double integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How would one go about evaluating:

$\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{x+y}{\sinh\left(x\right)+\sinh\left(y\right)}\,dy\,dx$

Putting this through Wolfram Alpha gives a value that is very close to (or equal to) $\pi^3$, but if this is the case, how could I go about proving it?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Sums_of_arguments

Comment: Hint: use the substitution $\frac{x+y}2=t;\, \frac{x-y}2=z$, getting decoupling of the integrals

Comment: You can now post an answer to your own question, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using trig identities for hyperbolic functions:

$\displaystyle\frac{x+y}{\sinh\left(x\right)+\sinh\left(y\right)} = \left(x+y\right)\operatorname{csch}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$

Going off a suggestion in the comments, we can use two *u*-substitutions:

$\begin{align}
u &= \frac{x+y}{2} \\
v &= \frac{x-y}{2}
\end{align}$

to get:

$\begin{align}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{x+y}{\sinh\left(x\right)+\sinh\left(y\right)}\,dy\,dx &= \displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\left(x+y\right)\operatorname{csch}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\,dy\,dx \\
&= 2\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}u\operatorname{csch}u\operatorname{sech}v\,du\,dv \\
&= 2\left(\frac{\pi^{3}}{2}\right) \\
&= \pi^3
\end{align}$

Comment: How did you evaluate the final double integral?

Comment: @TedShifrin You can integrate $u$ and $v$ independently.

Comment: @HuanyuShi I am well aware of that. I do not know how to do the $u$ integration in elementary terms.

Comment: @TedShifrin There are many ways to solve this integral, I offer one:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh x}\, \mathrm{d}x &= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh x}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&=4\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-2kx}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&=4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} =4\cdot \frac{\pi^2}{8}= \frac{\pi^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$